# Using JQuery in node-webkit not possible

Tags: jquery, node.js, node-webkit

I'm trying to use jquery in the node-webkit 0.12.3 Version. I have done this succesfully by adding

```
<script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

to my index.html.

I have done this succesfully in version 0.12.2 but now i am getting an error that i cannot understand. I am getting a warning in the log.

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

Right after that the error

> Failed to load resourcejquery-2.1.4.js:8630 
>   file:///.../jquery-2.1.4.js
>   send

which is the following line
`xhr.send( options.hasContent && options.data || null );`

I have read that I could be a Problem that I am accesing the filesystem of another app but this is not correct.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can use jQuery (I'm using 1.7.2) -- but the `file://` protocol might be causing the problem. I'm running an `express` server so that all requests correctly mimic a web server - though I also notice that *synchronous* HTTP requests cause `nw.js` 0.12.3 to stop responding.

Answer (score 1):

you should use nodejs module just like "superagent" instead ajax. if your want to use jquery you should host local http server and on your server add domain for cros;